# Using RxBiding inside a custom view

Tags: android, rx-binding

What's the best practice when you want to emit an `Observable` with `RxView.clicks(mCustomView)`, but a custom action is also needed inside the View itself?

Multiple subscribers? One being in charge with the custom action inside the View?

Or, perhaps better, using `Observable.map()` and make the change this way? Then the Observable must reside inside the View.

Or another solution? What do you think? Thanks.